# Revoke System Administrator Clone to become "Standard User?"

Tags: permissions, profile, custom-profile

I have gotten conflicting answers from the in-person and google querying: would cloning a System Administrator profile and removing the Admin/Setup permissions effectively render the Profile a "Standard User" profile?

In other words, does cloning a System Administrator Profile convey any irrevokable "Admin" priveliges to that Profile?

The reverse of that question of course is could a clone of the "Standard User" profile have so many permissions added that the profile effectively becomes an Administrator-capable profile?

I ask because I am trying to suss out the nuances of approaching User permissions with the different options Salesforce provides (Profiles, Permission Sets, Roles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System administrator and Standard user both are salesforce license profile, so if you clone any of them you can add or remove as many permissions as you want.

You can add permissions in Standard user cloned profile and can make it equivalent to System admin also You can remove some permissions from System admin cloned profile and can make it equivalent to Standard user.

It is the license of profiles which make sure that you don't assign irrelevant or too much permissions. For example a chatter license profile can never be make equivalent to System admin profile.

This way salesforce prevents you from misusing the system. As chatter license are cheaper or free than costly salesforce license.